# I fail to insert the values to tkinter listbox

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have written this piece of code to implement data to Listbox when I open a file, though there is an AttributeError, I have failed to understand to fix this error.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import csv
from imdb import IMDb


class STproject:

    def __init__(self,app): #1

        self.mlb=LabelFrame(app, text='Movie Recommendation Engine')
        self.mlb.grid()
        self.lframe3=LabelFrame(self.mlb,text="Movies/Users",background='purple')
        self.lframe3.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.framebutton=Frame(self.mlb,background='pink',height=50,width=50)
        self.framebutton.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.buttonsnlabels()

    def buttonsnlabels(self):

        self.ratingbutton=Button(self.framebutton,text='Upload Rating',command=lambda :self.file2())
        self.ratingbutton.grid()
        self.lb1 = Listbox(self.lframe3)
        self.lb1.grid()
        self.lb1.insert(self.emp2) //self.emp2 its locally ?

    def file2(self):
        umovies=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        f=open(umovies)
        self.emp2=[]
        self.csv_file2 = csv.reader(f)
        for line2 in self.csv_file2:
            self.emp2.append(line2[2])

root=Tk()
root.title()
application=STproject(root)
root.mainloop()
```

and here you have the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Umer Selmani/Desktop/voluntarily/Voluntiraly.py", line 846, in <module>
    application=STproject(root)
  File "C:/Users/Umer Selmani/Desktop/voluntarily/Voluntiraly.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.a=self.emp2[1]
AttributeError: STproject instance has no attribute 'emp2'
```

Comment: you can use `command=self.file2`

Comment: `.insert(self.emp2)` is executed after button is created, not after user clicked button. You have to use `.insert(self.emp2)` in `file2()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this error because your `.insert(self.emp2)` is executed after button is created, not after user clicked button. And at this moment you don't have `self.emp2` yet - you create it later in `file2()`.

You have to use `.insert(self.emp2)` in `file2()`

**EDIT:** You have to use insert inside `for` loop and add every item separatelly

```
            self.lb1.insert('end', line2[2])
```

so you could skip `self.emp2` if you don't need it later

Or you have to use `*` to put items from list in separated lines

```
self.lb1.insert('end', *self.emp2)
```

Code

```
def buttonsnlabels(self):

        self.ratingbutton = Button(self.framebutton, text='Upload Rating', command=self.file2)
        self.ratingbutton.grid()

        self.lb1 = Listbox(self.lframe3)
        self.lb1.grid()


def file2(self):
        #self.emp2 = []

        umovies = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

        f = open(umovies)
        self.csv_file2 = csv.reader(f)

        for line2 in self.csv_file2:
            #self.emp2.append(line2[2])
            self.lb1.insert('end', line2[2])

        #self.lb1.insert('end', *self.emp2)
```

Comment: Can you please help me out how to implement for example only first 5 row of a certain column?

Comment: Should i append the values to empty list, and then inserting from list, or is there any method without appending the values into empty list?

Comment: see code in `file2` in answer - skip commented lines - it appends directly to listbox without using empty list.